# Debian- public wifi connection

Tags: linux, debian, connection, wireless-access-point, wifi-configuration

I try to connect a public **password-less** wifi network. My /etc/network/interfaces file is

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wireless-essid asd
```

I did

```
# ifup wlan0
```

But i couldn't get ip from dhcp, it says as:
*No DHCPOFFERS received.*
I can connect with wpa_supplicant to my wpa2 home network, but i couldn't connect my school's public network.

--Edit--
I can see the network with :

```
# iwlist scan
```

--Edit2--
After restart, it connected the network and internet, but after 10 minutes, disconnected from internet but not from the network(I can see the gateway IP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232632/issues-with-connecting-to-open-wifi-network-via-etc-network-interfaces) , I added **allow-hotplug wlan0**

```
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wireless-essid asd
```